# Need an elegant solution to select webform's dom element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

```
$("*[id$='blahblah']")
```

is a good way but not perfect when

```
<asp:Button ID="chk" runat="server" Text="chk" />
<asp:Button ID="unchk" runat="server" Text="unchk" />
```

Is there a simple&&elegant way to select them precisely? (A complicated function like

```
if(id.indexOf('$')!=-1){/*blahblah*/}
```

is certainly not simple&&elegant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framework is your friend.

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0+, you can use the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) property of the control like this.

```
<asp:Button ID="chk" runat="server" Text="chk" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:Button ID="unchk" runat="server" Text="unchk" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

If the mode is set to Static the ID of the control won't change no matter what. ( ie, in Master Page and all ). Now you can elegantly call it like.

```
var b1 = $('#chk');
var b2 = $('#unchk');
```

The other way which looks elegant to me is giving button CssClass and then using the selector for class. ie, `.classname`

Comment: it's coooool but we still use .NET3.5 :(

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what are you asking here, but take a look at [jQuery('#id')](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

So you can have:

```
var ckeck = $('#chk');
var unckeck = $('#unchk');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use <%= %> in your markup to grab the control's ID if you are not using ASP.NET 4+

```
<asp:Button ID="example" Text="I should be hidden" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#<%= example.ClientID %>').hide();
    });
</script>
```